# When attempting to add a link to a D2L module using a QuickLink plugin, why is the parentNode set to -1 in the LTI data?

Tags: desire2learn, lti

I've created a QuickLink remote plugin in a Desire2Learn test environment.  This results in a link to the launchpoint of that plugin appearing in the "Add Existing Activities" drop down in the Content tab.  I've selected a module in the left navigation, so I would expect that when I launch the plugin from the drop down, the LTI request would contain information about the module.  Specifically I would expect to see an id for the module after the parentNode in the following LTI parameter custom_links_import_service_url:

```
[URL of test environment]/d2l/lms/remoteplugins/coursebuilder/ImportService.d2l?parentNode=-1&pluginId=1c57285b-72ba-4f88-a8e6-b5c6e2d7cc8d
```

Or in the launch_presentation_return_url:

```
[URL of test environment]/d2l/lp/quicklinks/ext/create?ou=6764&parentNode=-1&pluginId=1c57285b-72ba-4f88-a8e6-b5c6e2d7cc8d
```

But no matter what module I choose, the parentNode always shows up as -1.  So I have no way of knowing from the LTI data what module D2L plans to insert my content into and, for that reason, an insert fails.

When doing something similar using the Course Builder (dragging a plugin into a module) the LTI data does give me a pointer to the module:

```
[URL of test environment]/d2l/lms/remoteplugins/coursebuilder/ImportService.d2l?parentNode=921&pluginId=001563ac-7c61-4477-af8f-3b4930a8ec65
```

Here the parentNode is 921.

Why is it always -1 when using the QuickLink plugin?

Answer (score 1):

That appears to me to be a defect with the Quicklink Remote Plugin build type's implementation. I would recommend that you report this as a defect to D2L's support desk through your organization's approved  support contact or partner manager.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation following this original question and response revealed that the QuickLink Remote Plugin is working as designed. Rather than embedding the module information in the URL, the Learning Environment expects you to redirect the user's browser to the launch_presentation_return_url address with query parameters as documented in the [Launch Presentation Return topic](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html#launch-presentation-return).

To try a working example of this Remote Plugin type yourself, you can use the Remote Plugin Test Service Sample, described on the [Valence Developer Blog](http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/11/11/making-development-easier-with-the-remote-plugins-test-service/).